# An application about Plancherel’s Equality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have trouble proving this equality: 
If $0<b<1$ and $
f \in L^{2}[0,1], \text { then }$ $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|\left\langle f, e^{2 \pi i b n x}\right\rangle\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{b}\|f\|_{2}^{2}
$.
 I think the correct way to solve this is Plancherel’s Equality but I have trouble applying the Plancherel’s Equality to this problem. And I can't see why $b<1$ is required. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac  1 b f(\frac x b)$ for $0 <x <b$ and $0$ for $b \leq x <1$. Apply Plancherel  to this $L^{2}[0,1]$ function.

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks.